# Wakanda Enterprise Server Install No Server administration page

Tags: server, administration, wakanda

After installing Wakanda Enterprise server version 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS we can't open the Wakanda Server Administration page for starting a solution. Ports 4433 and 8080 have been enabled on the Ubuntu server.
The page shows the Wakanda icon in the tab but the page stays blank.

Answer (score 1):

Administration panel is available at http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin

Source : [Dashboard section](https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-prod)

Comment: Also, make sure to enable CORS for 127.0.0.1:8080 and the runner service.